# How to get id of selected value from dropdownlist using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to get an id from dropdownlist as it is giving null in jquery. Secondly i want to ask about syntax of dropdown i am not getting how it is working.

```
  <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2"><b>OrderStatus</b></label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("OrderStatusList", new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["OrderList"], "Text", "Value"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control", id = "orderStatusList" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessage("OrderStatusList", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


 $("#orderStatusList").change(function () {
            debugger;
            var orderStatusId = $("#orderStatusList").find('option:selected').val();
                if (orderStatusId != "") {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "OrderList")' + '?OrderStatusId=' + orderStatusId,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.success == true) {

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                alert("Inavlid Id");
                            } }
                    });
                }
            });
```

This the drop down and the jquery where i am getting the id of selected item. Here i am not getting that what's the "Text" and "Value" are taking.

```
 OrderViewModel model = new OrderViewModel();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> statusList = db.OrderStatus.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = (s.StatusName).ToString() }).ToList();
        ViewData["OrderList"] = statusList;
        //model.OrderStatusList = statusList;
```

This is my controller and here i have made the Ienumerable list of order status in order view model. I want to store list in model but i cannot because my view is of IEnumerable type as it is working with foreach loop so in dropdown it is not taking a model values so i had to do like this. I am comfortable with DropDownListFor . This is my first time that I have done with this syntax

[DropDown Ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp6JW.png)

Comment: is your dropdown filling properly in browser?, if yes then please post it

Comment: Orders and OrderStatus are different tables. I have not made orderstatus view model as it was not needed but i made the the list of OrderStatus Of type IEnumerable in OrderViewModel and called it in Order's Controller

Comment: Yes dropdown is filling properly

Comment: so, on the dropdown change event you want selected option id?

Comment: Yes i want an id of selected option

Comment: I have added link of screenshot named "DropDown Ss"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownList("OrderStatusList", new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["OrderList"], "Text", "Value"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control", id = "orderStatusList" }
```

Please change this to

```
@Html.DropDownList("OrderStatusList", new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["OrderList"], "Value", "Text"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control", id = "orderStatusList" }
```

Secondly in controller make following changes your value should point to statusId instead of value and text property should point to s.StatusName:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> statusList = db.OrderStatus.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = (s.StatusName).ToString() }).ToList();
```

Please bind Text and Value here you are only binding text to value property.

Answer (score 1):

try below solution

```
<div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-horizontal">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-lg-2"><b>OrderStatus</b></label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                  @Html.DropDownList("OrderStatusList", new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["OrderList"], "Text", "Value"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control", id = "orderStatusList" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessage("OrderStatusList", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>
               </div>
              </div>
   </div>

 $("#orderStatusList").change(function () {

            var orderStatusId = $(this).val();
                if (orderStatusId != "") {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "OrderList")' + '?OrderStatusId=' + orderStatusId,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.success == true) {

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                alert("Inavlid Id");
                            } }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Comment: you want selected option value? if yes then above code will work, and if you talking about id then not clear about it, please let me know which id you want

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#orderStatusList').val();
```

or

```
$("#orderStatusList option:selected").val()
```

Comment: Still not getting after trying this